Logs ignoring Log Level specified
if i run this code in the annonimous console:
System.debug('testing logs FLAGS (sem flag explicita)'); 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.NONE, 'testing logs FLAG'); 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'testing logs FLAG'); 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'testing logs FLAGS');
System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'testing logs FLAGS'); 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'testing logs FLAGS'); 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.FINE, 'testing logs FLAGS'); 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.FINER, 'testing logs FLAGS'); 
System.debug(LoggingLevel.FINEST, 'testing logs FLAGS');

why do i still get logs for all those flags, even if i only have INFO in the only current flag, for all categories, in setup?

i think i got: each level adds an increasing level of detail, so being the order:
(less detail) NONE / ERROR / WARN / INFO / DEBUG / FINE / FINER / FINEST (most detail),
each level add more information, and includes all previous flags, of less detailed levels. And each category has it's own level
i was getting that error because even if i had my custom level with INFO only for apex, and all the others to none, when i refreshed the logs page, i would still get a default flag with SFDC_DevConsole (and this i still don't know why). By changing the filters for this default flag, i get what i needed
